# conditional expectation with updated information

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

> Let
>
> $$\epsilon_{t+1} = \rho\epsilon_t + \eta_{t+1}$$
>
> $$E_t[r_{t+k}|\eta_t] = \phi^k \eta_t$$
>
> Can we say that
>
> $$E_t[r_{t+1}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \phi^k \eta_{t-k}$$
>
> Are there any conditions for this to be valid?

I would have thought that if

$$E_t[r_{t+k}|\eta_t] = \phi^k \eta_t$$

then with $k=1$

$$E_t[r_{t+1}|\eta_t] = \phi \eta_t$$

so the question is if

$$E_t[r_{t+1}|\eta_t] = E_t[r_{t+1}]$$

Comment: Is $\eta_t$ random ? Do we have information about its distribution?

Comment: No you can't say that because the formula for $E[r_{t+1}]$ is still random.